# How to release the disk space of Linux home directory under another system

Tags: ubuntu, disk-cleanup

I have a SSD with an Ubuntu system, but for some reason the disk space is full. Now it is impossible to enter the system normally.  How can I release disk space and reenter the system normally?

[image]

This is the display of output under the SSD home directory

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             4003888        0   4003888   0% /dev
tmpfs             807824     3456    804368   1% /run
/dev/sda2       39110168 21066332  16027428  57% /
tmpfs            4039104        0   4039104   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            4039104        0   4039104   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1           128      128         0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop0        382848   382848         0 100% /snap/anbox/186
/dev/loop2        119552   119552         0 100% /snap/core/14399
/dev/loop3        119552   119552         0 100% /snap/core/14447
/dev/loop4         56960    56960         0 100% /snap/core18/2667
/dev/loop5         56960    56960         0 100% /snap/core18/2679
/dev/loop6         64768    64768         0 100% /snap/core20/1738
/dev/loop8         74752    74752         0 100% /snap/core22/484
/dev/loop7         64896    64896         0 100% /snap/core20/1778
/dev/loop11         8576     8576         0 100% /snap/evince/1017
/dev/loop9         74752    74752         0 100% /snap/core22/504
/dev/loop10        56448    56448         0 100% /snap/cups/872
/dev/loop12         5248     5248         0 100% /snap/evince/1020
/dev/loop13       168832   168832         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop14       224256   224256         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/loop15       224256   224256         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
/dev/loop16       354688   354688         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
/dev/loop22       180224   180224         0 100% /snap/musescore/228
/dev/loop23        14848    14848         0 100% /snap/simple-scan/785
/dev/loop17       354688   354688         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
/dev/loop24        47104    47104         0 100% /snap/snap-store/638
/dev/loop21        83328    83328         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
/dev/loop26        14208    14208         0 100% /snap/simple-scan/769
/dev/loop18       457088   457088         0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/44
/dev/loop19       463360   463360         0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/56
/dev/loop20        93952    93952         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop25        47104    47104         0 100% /snap/snap-store/599
/dev/loop27        50816    50816         0 100% /snap/snapd/17883
/dev/loop28        51072    51072         0 100% /snap/snapd/17950
/dev/loop31       302848   302848         0 100% /snap/vlc/2344
/dev/loop32       328192   328192         0 100% /snap/vlc/3078
/dev/loop30       384128   384128         0 100% /snap/telegram-desktop/4486
/dev/loop29       384128   384128         0 100% /snap/telegram-desktop/4470
/dev/sda4       29398012 26514444   1367180  96% /home
/dev/sda1         495648    11408    484240   3% /boot/efi
tmpfs             807820       40    807780   1% /run/user/1000
```

sdb is the SSD

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the output of `df -k`.

Comment: Can you enter the system "abnormally" ? If you can get in as root, there should be an extra 5% of disk (the system limits normal user space so root can still login), and you can sort out the file system (delete a runaway file, or move some stuff to another device). Or if you have a Live DVD from when you installed, boot from that and fix the problem.

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably the graphics environment unable to operate with the lack of the space. Linux text console environment is much more forgiving.

Text consoles commonly use VTs 1, 2, etc, while XWindow GUI used to sit on VT 7 (I am not so sure about Wayland). Press `Shift+Alt+F1` (... F2, etc.) to switch from GUI to text VT, login there and free some space by removing some files using `rm` (be cautious and don't remove something you might need). Then you can exit and switch back with `Alt+F7` (or whatever your GUI VT is) and try to login again. Or, simply press `Ctrl+Alt+Del`, it will send the system into orderly soft reboot and return in GUI login screen.

P.S. I don't see sdb in your df output. Are you sure?